# Подключение шрифтов для разных браузеров

Tags: css, google-fonts

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста. Подключаю шрифты для сайта таким образом:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sochi2014 Bold';
    src: url("http://xxxx.ru/podpiska/fonts/Sochi2014_Light.ttf"); 
} 

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sochi2014 Bold';
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.ru/podpiska/fonts/Sochi2014_Light.ttf"); 
}
```

Первый `font-face` для хрома, где после `http` нет `www` (иначе не подгружаются шрифты).

Второй `font-face` для мозиллы, где после `http` идет `www`.

*Devtools* мозиллы выдает такие предупреждения:

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Sochi2014 Light" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://xxxx.ru/podpiska/fonts/Sochi2014_Light.ttf  promo_test.css:13:12
>
> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://xxxx.ru/podpiska/fonts/Sochi2014_Light.ttf. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).

Как избавиться от этих предупреждений?
Может как то по другому подключать шрифты? Хотел через *Google Fonts*, но там нужных мне шрифтов не оказалось.

Comment: Если не вдаваться в подробности, то сайт с которого вы пытаетесь тырить шрифты запрещает их у себя тырить, вот и все. Придется их скачать, сохранить к себе на сервак и грузить уже оттуда.

Comment: Ну то есть сильно упрощая веб устроен таким образом, что Вы не можете с сайта скажем mySite.com грузить что-то с otherSite.com если otherSite.com этого явно не разрешает.